# Is there a way to call vim macro's inside shell script?

Tags: shell, vim

I am doing data processing in unix environment using shell script and vim macros. Here are the steps:

1. I use grep to get some useful lines from log files.
2. Macros inside vim are used to manipulate the data.
3. Again, use shell script to process the data.

I have to do this for many files. So,  I am wondering is there a way to call vim's macro in shell script through special wrapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can trigger recorded macros, e.g.

```
$ vim -c "normal! @q" file
```

this is a fragile approach.

### Alternatives

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using *non-interactive tools* like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively:

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
REM Windows
call vim -N -u NONE -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Note: silent batch mode `-s-ex` messes up the Windows console, so you may have
to do a `cls` to clean up after the Vim run.

```
# Unix
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the "commands.ex" file doesn't
exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read
the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from
stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the - argument.

### Full Automation

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation
of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the
user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "commands.vim" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                  Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                  with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It helps me to do better way. Since I like vim macro's magic, I have done with awk and sed.

Answer (score -1):

I am not clearly known your require. but maybe vim -s, vim -W, vim -W can help you!