# Apply a VIM key sequence to all files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, vim

I want to indent all my files using the command `gg=G` of VIM. Is there anyway to write a script to do that ?

I imagine it can be something like

```
find . | xargs -n 1 | vim [ with some option to indent ]
```

I am quite sure `vim -c` may help, but not sure what is `gg=G` equivalent..

Comment: It would seem much easier to use `sed` to accomplish indentation rather than vim.

Comment: @JimGarrison `gg=G` is not just doing one level indent. it re-formats your file. sed is nice tool, but it has no idea about syntax. You can try to mess a java/c/c++/... src file up, then do `gg=G` you will realize that it is really hard job for sed.

Comment: You can do this with `:normal`, or by sourcing a Vimscript. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15677418/813602) for details.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a dedicated program for your language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim has two options you could take a look: (from man vim)

```
 -s {scriptin}
                   The script file {scriptin} is read.  The characters in the file are interpreted as if you had typed them.  The same can be  done  with  the  command
                   ":source! {scriptin}".  If the end of the file is reached before the editor exits, further characters are read from the keyboard.
```

and

```
  -w {scriptout}
               All the characters that you type are recorded in the file {scriptout}, until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want to create a script file to be
               used with "vim -s" or ":source!".  If the {scriptout} file exists, characters are appended.
```

that means, you could record your key sequence by `vim -w script` for example `gg=GZZ` then you could `vim -s script file`

I think vimgolf uses this mechanism too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bufdo` to apply a command to all buffers, and `normal gg=G` to run the normal mode command `gg=G`. And `wqall` to save them all.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.. the files are not in my buffers to begin.

Comment: You can just open them all with `vim` (like `vim *` or something).

Comment: Thanks, that's doable but quite messy. I do not want to open a ton of files.. with potentially large files. I will see if there is any better answer without the need of open all the files.

Comment: Well, then you can just run `normal gg=G` and `wq` on each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following all within vim.

```
:args `find .`
:argdo normal gg=G
:argdo w
```

This builds up the `argslist` and then runs the normal command `gg=G` on each file in  the argslist. Then we save each file in the argslist. Note: this requires `set hidden`.

Drew Neil over at [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org) has some nice screencasts about this subject:

- [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/)
- [Populating the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/)
- [Using :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/)
- [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/)

For more help see:

```
:h argslist
:h 'hidden'
```